# Proxy app from terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, proxy

Is it possible to start an app from the terminal and assigning it a proxy without modifying the system proxy settings? Note: I do not have admin privileges on this machine. It's a Mac running High Sierra 10.13.6.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of open source tools (`curl`, `wget`, ...) support the use of environment variables to set proxy.
For example, below is an extract of `wget` manpage:

```
ENVIRONMENT
       Wget supports proxies for both HTTP and FTP retrievals.  The standard way to
       specify proxy location, which Wget recognizes, is using the following
       environment variables:

       http_proxy
       https_proxy
           If set, the http_proxy and https_proxy variables should contain the URLs
           of the proxies for HTTP and HTTPS connections respectively.

       ftp_proxy
           This variable should contain the URL of the proxy for FTP connections.
           It is quite common that http_proxy and ftp_proxy are set to the same
           URL.

       no_proxy
           This variable should contain a comma-separated list of domain extensions
           proxy should not be used for.  For instance, if the value of no_proxy is
           .mit.edu, proxy will not be used to retrieve documents from MIT.
```

Answer (score 0):

If the app itself does not have proxy options, there are commercial solutions that allow this, for example [Proxifier](https://www.proxifier.com/):

> Redirect connections of any internet app (browser, email, database, game, etc.) through a proxy.

You might have to test whether this app requires admin privileges, at least for installation.

Also, there may be issues with system-wide proxies that are enforced by company policy, which you cannot overrule, or which would interfere with custom proxy rules you want to set up. See also [the documentation](https://www.proxifier.com/docs/mac-v2/proxy.htm):

> If you were using proxies before you installed Proxifier you should disable any built-in proxy settings. Your applications should then be configured to connect “directly” to the Internet (rather than through proxies).

In general, if this is a case of “I want to override a company policy”, you should deal with this problem on a human/sysadmin level rather than attempting such workarounds.